# Magento - Product flat functionality with many attributes

Tags: magento, product, flat

So we have over a hundred filterable attributes divided over more than hundred categories (mostly 5-20 per category). The flat table can't contain so many keys so will have to look in the eav table anyway on both product list and product normal page.

Is the flat product of any use now? Can I just as well turn it off and save possible troubles with it?

Answer (score 0):

With filterable attributes you mean, you're using them for layered navigation in catalog and catalogsearch?

If you don't have any other listing where you don't need all your attributes like topsellers etc. I don't know where the product flat table could help you.